# How to get data and tabulate it from multiple links on a single website HTML

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

This code is executing and providing multiple links to data from a single website . Code mentions the website . Website has data from multiple links which then tabulates as one single table

Can you suggest what are the changes to made in this code in order to get data without importing any further libraries and tabulate it?

```
    #import libraries
    import re 
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import urllib.request as ur
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    s = ur.urlopen("https://financials.morningstar.com/ratios/r.html?t=AAPL")
    s1 = s.read()
    print(s1)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(ur.urlopen('https://financials.morningstar.com/ratios/r.html?t=AAPL'),"html.parser")
title = soup.title
print(title)

text = soup.get_text()
print(text)
links = []
for link in soup.find_all(attrs={'href': re.compile("http")}):
    links.append(link.get('href'))

print(links)
```

The expected results should be a tabular form of ratios as listed each of which can be listed as dictionary with key being the year and value being the ratio

Comment: Those BeautifulSoup selectors don't look right at all. Read [the docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for how to select elements correctly.

Comment: There are 17 rows under key ratios that have data (excluding year headers). Which do you want?

Comment: @QHarr i want all of them with year and their values

Comment: Then you need an additional identifier for the row I think

Comment: @QHarr this particular website has multiple links to source the data . Can we get the data directly from the link and tabulate ? Can you suggest additional identifier ?

Comment: what is an example link for the source?

Comment: What is wrong with having them as tables?

Comment: @QHarr nothing. But for my particular problem i need it as dictionaries and later as tables

Comment: @QHarr it is mentioned in the code

Answer (score 1):

1) Here is one way with selenium and pandas. You can view the final structure [here](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=57e4554ee62f409aaca31b6925f6865c). The content is JavaScript loaded so I think it likely you need additional libraries.

2) There was a call being made to this:

https://financials.morningstar.com/finan/financials/getKeyStatPart.html?&callback=jsonp1555262165867&t=XNAS:AAPL&region=usa&culture=en-US&cur=&order=asc&_=1555262166853

that returns json containing info for the page. You might try using `requests` with that.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
import copy

d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get('https://financials.morningstar.com/ratios/r.html?t=AAPL')
tables = WebDriverWait(d,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#tab-profitability table")))
results = []

for table in tables:
    t = pd.read_html(table.get_attribute('outerHTML'))[0].dropna()
    years = t.columns[1:]
    for row in t.itertuples(index=True, name='Pandas'):
        record = {row[1] : dict(zip(years, row[2:]))}
        results.append(copy.deepcopy(record))
print(results)

d.quit()
```

---

You end up with all 17 rows being listed. First two rows shown here with row 2 expanded to show pairing of years with values.

[image]

Comment: I would welcome comments on improving the above (though I know I could also ask at code review later).

Comment: thank you . This works great :) . If however i were to replace the website with a list of input of websites say a list and then to tabulate it , what changes have to made ?

Comment: as for code , i downloaded selenium and defined the path . otherwise the code is perfect

Comment: Depends whether those website have the same structure. Do they?

Comment: no . they will have different structure . What to do then ?

Comment: Without a full url list it is going to be tough for anyone to do this.

Comment: Nice one, QHarr!!